# constructor is implicitly deleted because its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain me why using constructor marked as `default` will have the error but the other one doesn't have. My understanding is they are very much similar.
Thanks.

```
class B {
public:
    B() {
        throw int(42);
    }
};

class A {
public:
    A() noexcept = default; // error: use of deleted function ‘A::A()’
                            // note: ‘A::A() noexcept’ is implicitly deleted because
                            // its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification ‘’
    //A() noexcept : m_b{}{}
    B m_b;
};
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: compiles OK on gcc, clang and msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/x4jhaoWE8. Which compiler and version are you using ?

Comment: GCC 8.x. I've tested with C++11 -> C++17, neither of them could be compiled successfully.

Comment: I see it happens with gcc 8.x and agree that both ctors are very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, the declaration of the constructor was already ill-formed, the idea being that the defaulted function ought to behave **identically** to the implicit declaration.  Your explicit implementation has no such restriction: `noexcept` functions are allowed to call potentially throwing functions, and the behavior is even well-defined if they throw.

In C++14 it was relaxed to be merely deleted in that case.  Later it [was realized](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1286r2.html) that even that was too restrictive (and difficult to implement correctly), so it was relaxed again: now the exception specification can be anything (but there’s still an automatic one for defaulted functions).

Both of these changes were **retroactive**, so you’ll see a dependence on compiler version more than language version.

Note that none of this depends on the actual `throw` in `B::B`: that constructor is **potentially** throwing regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit default constructor exception specification differs from your declaration of explicit default constructor. Here's the relevant (although outdated) part of the standard:

> If a function that is explicitly defaulted is declared with an exception-specification that is not compatible (15.4) with the exception specification on the implicit declaration, then
>
> - if the function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is defined as deleted;
> - otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

In 2019 the [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1286r2.html) was made to change this behaviour. As I understand in c++20 your code will run just fine.